# Find norm of an operator from $h^1$ to $l^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $$h^1=\left\{ (u_n)_{n \geq 0}\: \middle|       \:u_n \in \mathbb{C}, \,\sum_{n \geq 0}{(n^2+1)|u_n|^2 < \infty} \right\}$$
with the norm
$$\lVert u \rVert_{h^1} = \sum_{n \geq 0}{(n^2+1)|u_n|^2}$$

and let $T:h^1 \rightarrow \ell^2$ (with usual definition of $\ell^2$ space) such that
\begin{split}
(Tu)_0 &= 0 \\
(Tu)_n &= nu_n + u_{n-1}.
\end{split}
I want to find the operator norm $\lVert T \rVert$.

I already showed that $T$ is linear and bounded with
$$ \lVert Tu \rVert_{\ell^2}^2 \leq 2 \lVert u \rVert_{h^1}^2.$$
Moreover I tried to find a sequence in $h^1$ such that $\lVert u \rVert_{h^1} = 1$ and $\lVert Tu \rVert_{\ell^2}^2 = 2$ but it doesn't come to an end.

Comment: Your norm is norm squared ….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $u$ such that $u_0=1$ and
$$
(nu_n + u_{n-1})^2 = 2n^2u_n^2 + 2 u_{n-1}^2
$$
(in the norm estimate one gets $\le$ instead of equality). This is equivalent to $u_n = \frac1n u_{n-1}$ or $u_n=\frac1{n!}$. Then $u\in h^1$ by quotient rule.

This implies
$$
\|Tu\|_{l^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (nu_n + u_{n-1})^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n^2u_n^2 + 2 u_{n-1}^2 \\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2n^2u_n^2 + 2 u_{n}^2 = 2 \|u\|_{h^1}^2.
$$